# Is there a way to make pop-ups open a little further away from my cursor?

Tags: user-interface, layout, graphics, visual-studio-code

I find the various pop-up items helpful but simultaneously deeply annoying as they often obscure the line above. I find it very useful to see the line above for context and it suddenly being hidden is a very jarring and uncomfortable sensation, akin to a physical invasion of personal, or even intimate space.

Although I want the information these pop-ups contain I am very close to disabling them for this reason. Many of my colleagues have disabled them already because they are "annoying"; I suspect their issue is one of proxemics too.

Is there a way I can make these pop-ups happen further away from my cursor? It wouldn't have to be by much, maybe just a line height further away, and maybe slightly off to the side. I feel this would solve the "annoying" issue for many people.